# Performing Hearts # 2 Classical Guitar

Tags: classical-music

Does anyone have the cover booklet of this CD, and if so, can you tell me if it says who actually plays the tracks on the CD, if it says this in the booklet?  Also, can you tell me what the tracks are on this CD?   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The track list is:

Vivaldi, Concerto in D Major, First Movement 3:34
Vivaldi, Concerto in D Major, Second Movement 5:04
Tarrega, Gran Jota 12:27
J. Malats, Serenada 5:04
Albéniz, Suite Espanola Op 471, Granada Serenade 4:34
Bach, Fugue in A Minor 5:02
Paganini, Grand Sonata for Guitar and Violin, Third Movement 8:19
Bach, Prelude Suite for Lute 6:25
M. Guiliani, Sonata Eroica 8:26

The track list is taken from the below image of the back cover of the CD. The image was [found on ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Performing-Hearts-2-Classical-Guitar-1997-CD/222499908552?_trkparms=aid%3D1110006%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131231084308%26meid%3Da8f10c008ef14a0b97e9f65cf9dd7ab4%26pid%3D100010%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D333735789772%26itm%3D222499908552%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DDefaultOrganic&_trksid=p2047675.c100010.m2109).

[image: Performing Hearts #2 back cover]
F. Carulli, Duet 6:20

I've not found information on the performer(s), but have emailed two libraries that may have the CD in their collections. Will update if and when I hear back.